# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client version 12

Tags: odp.net

I know that this is an issue that was fixed in the past, I even saw the post about it:
http://www.splinter.com.au/using-the-new-odpnet-to-access-oracle-from-c/
I encountered this issue and followed the post with one difference, instead of 11 I am using version 12 so I looked for the dll's with 12 in their name, I found all except OraOps12w.dll (I found OraOps12.dll).
is there a difference in the actions in this post between version 11 and 12 that I need to follow?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use the fully managed client (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` namespace)? That is just a single .NET assembly without the need for all that unmanaged DLLs.